# Having trouble parsing out 「私は今までの私ではない」

Tags: translation, verbs, possession

I've been struggling with the possessive and the statement of existence in the following phrase:

> 私は今までの私ではない

The easy part is "I am until now"...but then I get stuck on 「の私ではない」. By itself, I understand「ではない」to mean "am not," but then「の私」throws me: "of me"?

How off-base is the following interpretation?

> I haven't been myself until now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Parse

**私は** - I

**今までの私** - The person I used to be (until now/just recently)

**ではない** - am not

### **Roughly translated**

> I am not the person I used to be.

### Side note

For parsing sentences, a useful tool is putting a comma after particles like は and seeing how the ideas organize out.

Comment: Yes! This makes perfect sense. I didn't consider that 「今までの私」can be construed as its own lexical unit. The comma-after-particle trick is actually very helpful. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think  `の` here is a nominalizer, converting `今まで` (until now) into a noun phrase which then modifies the second `私`, resulting in `今までの私` ("me until now", i.e. "the person I used to be").

Combining it with the first `私は` and last `ではない`, we get:

> I'm not the person I used to be.